# Chapter Heading placement

Tags: chapters

I have a lot of short chapters so I would like the Chapter to go at the top of a page and text to immediately follow it.  In other words, not so much blank space.  Second, I would like to define a lab macro that just put the word Lab in front of the chapter name.

For example:

```
\lab {Blink}
```

should turn into:

```
\Chapter{Lab: Blink}
```

I therefore wrote a command:

```
\newcommand{\lab}[1]{\chapter{Lab: {#1}}}
```

I am just trying to understand if this should work.  It is not working, which could be due to something subtle.  I had a previously defined lab command and tried to comment it out.  If the above command is in fact correct, then I will start another question with a MWE for that purpose.

Comment: It will work, but it will add `Lab: ` in the `ToC` as well. Isn't changing `\chaptername` the better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro is probably breaking because `\chapter` is a "fragile" command. Add `\protected` and it should work (notice I had to change `\newcommand` to a plain `\def`):

```
\protected\def\lab#1{\chapter{Lab: {#1}}}
```

For spacing, I would suggest using the `titlesec` package. The following removes all vertical space before a chapter heading:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
            {\sffamily\bfseries}% formatting applied to all chapters
            {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter} % Used for numbered chapters only 
            {\baselineskip} % Vertical space between ``Chapter N'' and name of chapter
            {}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{\baselineskip}
```

Note that the `display` option puts vertical space between the chapter label ('Chapter 1') and the title ('Foo'). Remove it and change `\baselineskip` to `1em` (or another horizontal dimension) if you want them on the same line.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\protected\def\lab#1{\chapter{Lab: {#1}}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
            {\sffamily\bfseries}% format
            {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter} % Sans-serif, bold 
            {\baselineskip} % Vertical space between ``Chapter N'' and name of chapter
            {}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}

XXX.

\lab{FooBar}

ZZZ.

\chapter{Baz}

QQQ.

\end{document}
```

which gives (with Lab):

[image: Lab chapter]

and without:

[image: Chapter w/o Lab]

Note I didn't change the margins at all, so it looks like there is still a lot of vertical space above the chapter. Using `the fullpage` or `geometry` packages would recover that space too.

Answer (score 2):

Lacking a really working scenario, I suggest to change the `\chaptername` rather:

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lab:~}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{FooBar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Other options: Change `\@makechapterhead`, but I suggest this only if there's more to be done than just changing the title